# How can I tell what this process is from netstat -AB?

Tags: windows-7, windows, java, netstat, teamcity

I need to find out which process is running on port 8888. I have used the 'netstat -AB' command in the command prompt however it does not show me the information. It seems to have a problem reading the process name.

[image]

NOTE: Originally this port was being blocked by java.exe (which I installed as part of setting up a team city server locally). However I have made sure to shut down all java.exe processes and I have uninstalled team city.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The process name is written on the following line after the connection details.

So port `8888` is open for listening by `MobileService.exe`

Comment: Which is either an iTunes executable: http://www.screenr.com/XRS or a 'Seagate Dashboard' program.

Comment: Lol yeah it is well done guys, just out of interest why does the one above it have no info though?